# Delete a pull request via Bitbucket API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

Am trying to delete a Pull request in Bitbucket (server edition) using HTTP DELETE API, but as suggested by bitbucket https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.1.0/bitbucket-rest.html?utm_source=%2Fstatic%2Frest%2Fbitbucket-server%2Flatest%2Fbitbucket-rest.html&utm_medium=301#idm45588159968240  I could not achieve it.

Could someone help to get the sample json entries to delete a Pull request?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this
curl -X DELETE --user user:password  [https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{owner}/{repo_slug}](https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/%7Bowner%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D)

Comment: we are using API version 1.0, so the syntax wont work. also it ends with repo_slug not with pull-requests too.

Answer (score 0):

For `Bitbucket Server` you can use the following `uri`: `/rest/api/1.0/projects/{PROJECT}/repos/{REPOSITORY}/pull-requests/{PULLREQUESTID}` (replace values within `{}` with correct values).

You need to add the correct headers:

- `Content-type: application/json`
- `Authorization: Basic ABC==` (for instance)

Then if you fire off a `HTTP DELETE` with the *version* in the body, you should get a `HTTP 204 (No Content)` back. The version should be a Json object: `{ "version" : 0 }`. You can retrieve which version the pull request is by first firing off an `HTTP GET` and looking at the response.